# Rails3: How to get a js.erb to insert HTML into your page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, escaping

I have a js.erb view, and it will replace certain things on my page. I want it to insert HTML but the HTML it inserts isn't rendered properly -- you can see the html tags.

I've tried numerous methods I could imagine, and even more that others have recommended, but none work. For example, in my js.erb:

```
var list = $("#list");
list.append("<li>first</li>");
list.append("<%= "<li>second</li>" %>");
list.append("<%= raw("<li>third</li>") %>");
list.append("<%= escape_javascript raw("<li>fourth</li>") %>");
list.append("<%= raw escape_javascript("<li>fifth</li>") %>");
list.append("<%= escape_javascript("<li>sixth</li>") %>");
list.append("<%= "<li>seventh</li>".html_safe %>");
list.append("<%= raw("<li>eigth</li>").html_safe %>");
list.append(unescape("<li>9th</li>"));
list.append(unescape("<%= raw("<li>10th</li>") %>"));
list.append(unescape(unescape("<li>11th</li>")));
```

And this is what I get appended to the list (note that this is copied straight from the HTML page, **not** the source of the page):

```
<li>first</li>&lt;li&gt;second&lt;/li&gt;<li>third</li><li>fourth</li><li>fifth</li>&lt;li&gt;sixth&lt;/li&gt;<li>seventh</li><li>eigth</li><li>9th</li><li>10th</li><li>11th</li>
```

**How do I do this so that the page will render it as HTML?**

Thanks!

*Note: I'm in the process of upgrading my app from Rails 2 to Rails 3, and this is something I've run into while upgrading. It worked **fine in Rails 2** that's why I think this is a js.erb issue and not a JavaScript issue.*

Comment: you need to fix your code. It seems that all the code text should have 4 spaces to the left of the line. (Google markdown help)

Comment: Hmm... it's currently in a pre/code block, and I tried putting 4 spaces too (within the pre/code block), but neither work. I also put a link to a gist with the code.

Comment: Ah.. it has to be 4 spaces, and outside the pre/code block. Thanks!

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking to append an actual list element to the page, and none of the 11 methods you've tried here are working, they all either escape the `<li>` tags once or twice, but you want to leave them as `<li>` tags?

Comment: Yes, I want to append an actual list element to the page. None of the 11 ones I've tried work.

Comment: I just generated a new rails app, tried it out. And it works fine. I don't know why mine doesn't yet, so I'll post it up here when I do.

Comment: To make the example above simple I cut out a lot of code. Unfortunately, this is one of the moments where the code I cut out had something to do with my problem. I'm actually using a remote form to upload things, and the server replies with create.js.erb. https://gist.github.com/663736 is the inline code I have on the page to override the form. Now, when I replace the create.js.erb with the code I put in the example above, it seems that it's always escaped. I think the problem lies in jquery.form. Still have to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So you understand this answer, read the comments of my question. It explains that I was using ajaxForm.*

In short, I think the response's mime type given back by Rails 3 isn't the same as Rails 2. I suspect this is the answer because while Googling for solutions, I found the [remotipart gem](https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart). That gem helps developers make Rails 3 remote file uploads "trivial".

I noticed that the instructions in the README state to wrap the javascript in a remotipart_response block. [Looking at line 3 of remotipart.rb](https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart/blob/master/lib/remotipart.rb#L3) I see that the **mime type is changed to HTML**.

Lo and behold, I implemented the gem and things work again.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
list.append("<li>third</li>");
```

OR,In case you render a partial

```
append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "show_new_pages")%>");
```